# Create new column based on condition in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

```
   PARENT_ID    ID   YR_MONTH    REWARD
1    1          11   201601        3
2    1          11   201605        9
3    1          13   201609        9
4    2          21   201601        6
5    2          21   201605        15
6    2          21   201609        9
7    3          31   201601        8
8    3          31   201605        9
9    3          32   201609        9
10   3          32   201610        9
```

I need to create a new column based Reward column.
where Reward is 9 put 1 else 0 based on the condition.

condition would be:

1. for particular parent_id, id check if there is no higher reward than 9 in previous yr_month if yes then 0 else 1
2. only first 9 will be marked as 1 else 0

Expected results:

```
   PARENT_ID    ID   YR_MONTH    REWARD  REWARD_STATUS
1    1          11   201601        3         0
2    1          11   201605        9         1
3    1          13   201609        9         1
4    2          21   201601        6         0
5    2          21   201605        15        0
6    2          21   201609        9         0
7    3          31   201601        8         0
8    3          31   201605        9         1
9    3          32   201609        9         1
10   3          32   201610        9         0
```

Comment: You have both mysql and oracle tags, which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case 
        when reward = 9 
        and sum(case when reward >= 9 then 1 else 0 end)  over(partition by parent_id order by yr_month) = 1
    then 1 else 0 end reward_status
from mytable t
```

The `case` expression returns `1` if:

- the `reward` of the current record has is `9`
- and there is not "previous" record for the same `parent_id` whose `reward` is equal or greater than `9`

If you are running MySQL, the `case` expression can be simplified as:

```
(
    reward = 9 
    and sum(reward >= 9)  over(partition by parent_id order by yr_month) = 1
) reward_status
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c665e37cfafc97b8d9611b51bca696c9)**:

```
PARENT_ID | ID | YR_MONTH | REWARD | REWARD_STATUS
--------: | -: | -------: | -----: | ------------:
        1 | 11 |   201601 |      3 |             0
        1 | 12 |   201605 |      9 |             1
        1 | 13 |   201609 |     12 |             0
        2 | 21 |   201601 |      6 |             0
        2 | 22 |   201605 |      9 |             1
        2 | 23 |   201609 |      9 |             0
        3 | 31 |   201601 |     15 |             0
        3 | 32 |   201605 |      9 |             0
        3 | 33 |   201609 |     12 |             0
        3 | 34 |   201610 |      9 |             0
```

Comment: I have updated the question can you please look in to it.

Comment: @Mohekar: just change `partition by parent_id` to `partition by id`.

Comment: But that will flag 0  when a particular id has more than one  9,  in this case we should only be flagging first occurrence of 9 based on yr_month rest should be zero .

Comment: @Mohekar: no, this flags only the first 9 per `id` (I just changed the MySQL-specific expression, if that’s what you are using).

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: @Mohekar: ok, so this works as you intended. Please try it against your real data, and you will find out.